# Python path.join behavior is different when run in Mac vs Windows

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, operating-system

### I want my Project, built in PYTHON to support Windows Linux MAC in any terminal(MAC, CYGWIN, Windows etc). I can able to achieve but I am facing some issue When I run the following

```
import os
mypath = os.path.join('users','scripts', 'pythonsample')
print mypath
```

### In windows command prompt output is

```
users\scripts\pythonsample
```

### In MAC terminal output is

```
users/scripts/pythonsample
```

### Also, when I run the following code

```
import glob
glob.glob(os.path.join('users','scripts', 'pythonsample','*.*'))
```

### In windows command prompt output is

```
[users/scripts\\pythonsample\\a1.py,
users/scripts\\pythonsample\\a2.py,
users/scripts\\pythonsample\\a3.py
users/scripts\\pythonsample\\a4.py]
```

### In MAC terminal output is

```
[users/scripts/pythonsample/a1.py,
users/scripts/pythonsample/a2.py,
users/scripts/pythonsample/a3.py
users/scripts/pythonsample/a4.py]
```

### So to parse and get get the name of the file without whole path becomes difficult in multiple platforms.

I can write a if else block to decide whether the script is running in Windows or MAC or CGYWIN.

```
import sys
#Output of below command is Win32, linux2, darwin, cgywin 
print(sys.platform)
```

but is there a easy way to accomplish this with out if else block?

Comment: What output do you actually _want_? Do you want POSIX-style paths even on Windows? Do you want to get Windows-style paths always instead of just in most cases on Windows? Or something different? And, most importantly, please explain _why_ you want that. What's wrong with what you're currently getting?

Comment: If glob.glob(somepath) output is same across the OS, then I can split the path using string.split('\\'). I will have to change this to string.split('\\') in windows string.split('/') in MAC.

Comment: Why are you using `string.split`? You're already using `os.path`; use its methods to split things too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what you should expect. On Windows, `os.path` gives you Windows-style paths; on Mac OS X, it gives you POSIX-style paths.

If you're looking to guarantee POSIX paths everything, don't use `os.path` at all, use `posixpath` instead.

On the other hand, if you've got paths that may be in POSIX format even on Windows (since most parts of Windows handle POSIX-style paths, and many tools generate POSIX-style paths) and want to guarantee that you've got a native path, call [`os.path.normpath`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath).

Comment: If glob.glob(somepath) output is same across the OS, then I can split the path using string.split('\\'). I will have to change this to string.split('\\') in windows string.split('/') in MAC.

Comment: You can always `s.split(os.pathsep)` if you want, which will split on backslashes on Windows and slashes everywhere else. But the whole point of `os.path` is that you don't have to deal with this nonsense. Just use the methods in `os.path` to deal with paths.

Comment: os.pathsep is not working in Windows. >>> c = os.path.abspath('..')
    >>> c.split(os.pathsep)
    ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop']

Comment: @Venkatesh: Sorry, yeah, I meant `os.sep`. Thanks for the correction; that could easily confuse future readers otherwise!